# I need a general mathematics equation for triangular wave and how to get for 32 and 2048 samples, a project for waveform generations in java

Tags: java

I saw this program
please explain
 //generate a triangular wave: triangle is sum of the sinusoidals //

```
void plotTriangular(Input newinfo, Graph new_g)
{
    Input info = newinfo;
    double tmp =0.0;
    Graph g = new_g;
    info.println();

    for (int i=1; i<= 400; i++)
    {
         for (double n=1.0; n<100.0; n+=2.0)
         { tmp+=(8.0*(info.amp)/(PI * PI))*(1.0/(n*n))*Math.sin(n*PI/2.0)
                    *Math.sin(n*(info.freq) *i* dx);
         }
         g.addPoint(i*dx,tmp);
         tmp=0.0;
    }

}
```

Comment: It's nice of you to share what you need and the source you ran into, but there is no actual question here. What does the source you have given have to do with what you need, what is not working, and where is the problem?

Comment: okay how do I generate a triangular waveform using java.. for 32 samples @RealSkeptic